# Need help to understand maintaining azure key vault in different environment and also to be able to use that in logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault

I have a logic app which makes HTTP call to Key Vault URI to get the secret needed to connect to external system. I have developed this in the dev resource group. I want to know how to setup the key vault from dev resource groups to other resource groups (test/prod). Also, how to migrate the logic app and get the secret per environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:) The solution is to use `ARM templates` and `ADO/any other pipeline`. You can create ARM templates with different parameters' values for different environments and use them to deploy your Logic App and Key vault to different environments.

[Logic App Template sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-resource-manager-templates-overview#workflow-definition-and-parameters):

```
{
   "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
   "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
   // Template parameters
   "parameters": {
      "<template-parameter-name>": {
         "type": "<parameter-type>",
         "defaultValue": "<parameter-default-value>",
         "metadata": {
            "description": "<parameter-description>"
         }
      }
   },
   "variables": {},
   "functions": [],
   "resources": [
      {
         // Start logic app resource definition
         "properties": {
            <other-logic-app-resource-properties>,
            "definition": {
               "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
               "actions": {<action-definitions>},
               // Workflow definition parameters
               "parameters": {
                  "<workflow-definition-parameter-name>": {
                     "type": "<parameter-type>",
                     "defaultValue": "<parameter-default-value>",
                     "metadata": {
                        "description": "<parameter-description>"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "triggers": {
                  "<trigger-name>": {
                     "type": "<trigger-type>",
                     "inputs": {
                         // Workflow definition parameter reference
                         "<attribute-name>": "@parameters('<workflow-definition-parameter-name')"
                     }
                  }
               },
               <...>
            },
            // Workflow definition parameter value
            "parameters": {
               "<workflow-definition-parameter-name>": { 
                  "value": "[parameters('<template-parameter-name>')]"
               }
            },
            "accessControl": {}
         },
         <other-logic-app-resource-definition-attributes>
      }
      // End logic app resource definition
   ],
   "outputs": {}
}
```

[Key Vault template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/2018-02-14/vaults):

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
  "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
  "location": "string",
  "tags": {},
  "properties": {
    "tenantId": "string",
    "sku": {
      "family": "A",
      "name": "string"
    },
    "accessPolicies": [
      {
        "tenantId": "string",
        "objectId": "string",
        "applicationId": "string",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "string"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "string"
          ],
          "certificates": [
            "string"
          ],
          "storage": [
            "string"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "vaultUri": "string",
    "enabledForDeployment": "boolean",
    "enabledForDiskEncryption": "boolean",
    "enabledForTemplateDeployment": "boolean",
    "enableSoftDelete": "boolean",
    "createMode": "string",
    "enablePurgeProtection": "boolean",
    "networkAcls": {
      "bypass": "string",
      "defaultAction": "string",
      "ipRules": [
        {
          "value": "string"
        }
      ],
      "virtualNetworkRules": [
        {
          "id": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "resources": []
}
```

Moreover, you can read this article to understand more about setting up your ADO pipelines: [Integrate ARM templates with Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/add-template-to-azure-pipelines)